# schtasks warning account information could not be set from php code

Tags: php, windows, scheduled-tasks

I am tring to run schtask from command line & it works correctly but I get an error :"The account information could not be set" when try to run it through PHP. My IIS version is 6.0

WARNING: The Scheduled task "BuildInstaller_6" has been created, but may not run because the account information could not be set.

The command line I am running is:

```
schtasks /create /tn "BuildInstaller31" /tr "E:\\TCS\\build\\scripts_5.2\\build.bat" /sc ONCE /st 13:25:30 /RU "TCS-SJCBUILD\\Administrator" /RP "xxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I just enable the Task Scheduler service.  Below is what worked for me:

```
FOR /F %%X IN (C:\list of workstations.txt) DO (
sc %%X config "Service name" start= auto
sc %%X start "Service Name"
schtasks /Create /TN "task name" /TR "path to task" /sc "daily" /st "time" /sd "date I want to start the task" /s \\%%X /U "username" /P "password"
pause
```